# Make a function that takes in 3 inputs from the user and validates them

Tags: python

Im trying to make a function that takes in 3 different inputs from the user and validates them to make sure they are all positive integers. Here's my current code

```
def get_positive_number(prompt):
 condition = False
 while condition == False:
 time = (input("Number of time units:"))
 if not time.isnumeric() or int(time) == 0:
    print("{} is not a valid number".format(time))
    condition = False
 elif int(time) > 0
    timeInt = int(time)
    condition = True
 while condition == False:
 atoms = (input("Number of atoms to simulate:"))
 if not atoms.isnumeric() or int(atoms) == 0:
    print("{} is not a valid number".format(atoms))
    condition = False
 elif int(atoms) > 0
    atomInt = int(atoms)
    condition = True
 while condition == False:
 radius = (input("Radius of beaker:"))
 if not radius.isnumeric() or int(radius) == 0:
    print("{} is not a valid number".format(radius))
    condition = False
 elif int(radius) > 0
    RadInt = int(time)
    condition = True
 pass
```

Comment: So what's wrong with it? (aside from the indentation issues under your 'while')

Comment: i was able to clean the code but when i did run it, it would continue to ask me for an input for a total of 9 times and then it would end

Answer (score 0):

In the future, I would encourage you to search your code for a lot of repetition. There are a lot of statements in your code that are almost exact copies of each other. In responding to the question as posted, the following code can be used to retrieve three positive integers, returned from the function as a list:

```
def get_positive_integers():
    positiveNums = []
    for i in range(0, 3):
        num=-1
        while num < 0:
            num = int(input("Enter a positive number {}".format(i)))
        positiveNums.append(num)
    return positiveNums
```

That being said, if you would like to have specific prompts (as in your example code), you could pass them to the function as a list, and use the `.format()` function to insert them.